# Django response.session behaving differently on localhost

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I have the following lines in a Django (v1.8) application.

```
{% if failed < 5 %}
    <div class="centered row">
        <div class="ui error message six wide column">
            <div class="content">
                The username and password provided do not match. Please try again.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

`failed` is being passed to the template like this:

```
if 'failed_logins' in request.session:
    request.session['failed_logins'] = request.session.get('failed_logins', 0) + 1
view = render(request, 'main/login.html', {
    'page_title': PAGE_TITLE,
    'failed': request.session['failed_logins']
})
```

On both my localhost and my server `failed` is showing as nothing when rendered in the template by `{{ failed }}`. This is to be expected, it's not there on the first load.

However on the localhost this causes the `{% if failed < 5 %}` to apparently evaluate to false, because the message is not shown. This makes sense to me, and since it worked testing on the localhost I assumed it was defined behavior.

On the server (AWS) though `{% failed < 5 %}` seems to evaluate to true. The message is displayed. This **also** makes sense to me, because maybe `None` is considered less than anything. It confuses me though, because it behaves one way on local server and another on a remote server.

What could cause this difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you on Python 2 on local, and Python 3 on the server? The way None is evaluated changed:

https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons

Comment: I thought of that after posting. The reverse of this is true. I have python 3 locally and python 2 on the machine. I am now looking for how to force `uwsgi` to use the python 3 I just installed on the server.